# create pandas dataframe from dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary of dictionaries of the form:

```
{'user':{movie:rating} }
```

For example,

```
{'Jill': {'Avenger: Age of Ultron': 7.0,
                            'Django Unchained': 6.5,
                            'Gone Girl': 9.0,
                            'Kill the Messenger': 8.0}
'Toby': {'Avenger: Age of Ultron': 8.5,
                                'Django Unchained': 9.0,
                                'Zoolander': 2.0}}
```

I want to convert this dict of dicts into a pandas dataframe with column 1 the user name and the other columns the movie ratings i.e.

```
user  Gone_Girl  Horrible_Bosses_2  Django_Unchained  Zoolander etc. \
```

However, some users did not rate the movies and so these movies are not included in the values() for that user key(). It would be nice in these cases to just fill the entry with NaN.

As of now, I iterate over the keys, fill a list, and then use this list to create a dataframe:

```
data=[] 
for i,key in enumerate(movie_user_preferences.keys() ):
    try:            
        data.append((key
                    ,movie_user_preferences[key]['Gone Girl']
                    ,movie_user_preferences[key]['Horrible Bosses 2']
                    ,movie_user_preferences[key]['Django Unchained']
                    ,movie_user_preferences[key]['Zoolander']
                    ,movie_user_preferences[key]['Avenger: Age of Ultron']
                    ,movie_user_preferences[key]['Kill the Messenger']))
    # if no entry, skip
    except:
        pass 
df=pd.DataFrame(data=data,columns=['user','Gone_Girl','Horrible_Bosses_2','Django_Unchained','Zoolander','Avenger_Age_of_Ultron','Kill_the_Messenger'])
```

But this only gives me a dataframe of users who rated all the movies in the set.

My goal is to append to the data list by iterating over the movie labels (rather than the brute force approach shown above) and, secondly, create a dataframe that includes all users and that places null values in the elements that do not have movie ratings.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You can pass the dict of dict to the DataFrame constructor:

```
In [11]: d = {'Jill': {'Django Unchained': 6.5, 'Gone Girl': 9.0, 'Kill the Messenger': 8.0, 'Avenger: Age of Ultron': 7.0}, 'Toby': {'Django Unchained': 9.0, 'Zoolander': 2.0, 'Avenger: Age of Ultron': 8.5}}

In [12]: pd.DataFrame(d)
Out[12]:
                        Jill  Toby
Avenger: Age of Ultron   7.0   8.5
Django Unchained         6.5   9.0
Gone Girl                9.0   NaN
Kill the Messenger       8.0   NaN
Zoolander                NaN   2.0
```

Or use the `from_dict` method:

```
In [13]: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
Out[13]:
                        Jill  Toby
Avenger: Age of Ultron   7.0   8.5
Django Unchained         6.5   9.0
Gone Girl                9.0   NaN
Kill the Messenger       8.0   NaN
Zoolander                NaN   2.0

In [14]: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
Out[14]:
      Django Unchained  Gone Girl  Kill the Messenger  Avenger: Age of Ultron  Zoolander
Jill               6.5          9                   8                     7.0        NaN
Toby               9.0        NaN                 NaN                     8.5          2
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the user names an individual column instead of an index?

Comment: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').reset_index()

Comment: Is there a way to make all info become in columns? ie column 1: Jill and Toby, column 2: all films repeated for each one (toby and jill) etc...

Answer (score 0):

This brute-force approach also appears to work, but iterating over the movie labels would still be more robust in my opinion.

```
data=[] 
for i,key in enumerate(movie_user_preferences.keys() ):
    try:            
        data.append((key
                    ,movie_user_preferences[key]['Gone Girl'] if 'Gone Girl' in movie_user_preferences[key] else 'NaN'
                    ,movie_user_preferences[key]['Horrible Bosses 2'] if 'Horrible Bosses 2' in movie_user_preferences[key] else 'NaN'
                    ,movie_user_preferences[key]['Django Unchained'] if 'Django Unchained' in movie_user_preferences[key] else 'NaN'
                    ,movie_user_preferences[key]['Zoolander'] if 'Zoolander' in movie_user_preferences[key] else 'NaN'
                    ,movie_user_preferences[key]['Avenger: Age of Ultron'] if 'Avenger: Age of Ultron' in movie_user_preferences[key] else 'NaN'
                    ,movie_user_preferences[key]['Kill the Messenger'] if 'Kill the Messenger' in movie_user_preferences[key] else 'NaN' ))

    # if no entry, skip
    except:
        pass


 user Gone_Girl Horrible_Bosses_2  Django_Unchained Zoolander  \
 0      Sam         6                 3               7.5         7   
 1      Max        10                 6               7.0        10   
 2   Robert       NaN                 5               7.0         9   
 3     Toby       NaN               NaN               9.0         2   
 4    Julia       6.5               NaN               6.0       6.5   
 5  William         7                 4               8.0         4   
 6     Jill         9               NaN               6.5       NaN   

 Avenger_Age_of_Ultron Kill_the_Messenger  
 0                   10.0                5.5  
 1                    7.0                  5  
 2                    8.0                  9  
 3                    8.5                NaN  
 4                   10.0                  6  
 5                    6.0                6.5  
 6                    7.0                  8
```