# Convert Dictionary to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, dictionary, dataframe

I have a Python dictionary of dictionaries that models the TF-IDF weights of words in a set of documents. Like that:

```
Corpus_dict = {"Doc1.txt": {'word1': XXXX , 'word2': XXXX , ... , wordn: xxx } 
               "Doc2.txt": {'word1': XXXX , 'word2': XXXX , ... , wordn: xxx }  
                ...
               "Docm.txt": {'word1': XXXX , 'word2': XXXX , ... , wordn: xxx }}
```

Where xxx is the TF-IDF value for each of n words. I'd like to convert it to the folowing Pandas Data Frame:

```
keys     Doc1      Doc2   ...   Docn

word1     xxx        xxx         xxx
word2     xxx        xxx         xxx
                      ...
word      nxxx       xxx         xxx
```

Can someone give me some help?

Sorry for bad english and thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create pandas dataframe from dictionary of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33157522/create-pandas-dataframe-from-dictionary-of-dictionaries)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use

```
pd.DataFrame(Corpus_dict)
```

It will give the dataframe which you wanted.

Found Similar Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33157522/create-pandas-dataframe-from-dictionary-of-dictionaries)

Answer (score 0):

The answer of your question is should be like in the below picture.

[image]