# Create DataFrame with 1 column from dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

I convert dictionary to pandas DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
my_dict = {
0: {1,5,8},
1: {2,7,6},
2: {8,3,7}
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index', dtype=None, columns=None)
print (df)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2
0  8  1  5
1  2  6  7
2  8  3  7
```

expected output:

```
number column
0      1,5,8
1      2,7,6
2      8,3,7
```

So column must contain simple container such as list or Series.

Question
[create pandas dataframe from dictionary of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33157522/create-pandas-dataframe-from-dictionary-of-dictionaries)
don't describe my problem because I dont need many columns.
Data must be stored in 1 column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple way of doing it

```
pd.DataFrame(my_dict.items(), columns=['number', 'column'])

   number  column
0     0  {8, 1, 5}
1     1  {2, 6, 7}
2     2  {8, 3, 7}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k:str(v).replace('{','').replace('}','') for k,v in my_dict.items()}, orient='index', dtype=None, columns=None).rename(columns={0:'column'})
df
```

prints

```
    column
0   8, 1, 5
1   2, 6, 7
2   8, 3, 7
```

we replace sets `{1,5,8}` with strings `'{1,5,8}'` and remove curly brackets from strings. Note the order changes because sets do not have a defined order

I assumed you wanted strings in that column

Answer (score 1):

```
df["new"]=df.iloc[:,:].values.tolist()

    0   1   2   new
0   8   1   5   [8, 1, 5]
1   2   6   7   [2, 6, 7]
2   8   3   7   [8, 3, 7]
```

Not sure if that is considered also a desired output, however, it regroups your elements in a list.

No need for the `iloc`